# number field not searchable

Tags: search

I have a number field in my list.

[image]

But I not able to search under the list search box.

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: did you try re-indexing your list?

Comment: No. Just try the re-indexing, still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Calculated field to remove comma’s from number field

For this example I’m going to display a number column (Alias) in a calculated field (Alias Calculated).
Create a calculated field:

**Do not copy and try to paste this formula, type it in your calculated field and make sure to use the Insert Column option.

2. Type in the following formula:
   =text(

Then double click on your number field in the Insert Column box

then type:
,”0″)

Your formula should display something like this: =text([Alias],”0″)
Choose a number field, with 0 decimal places and click OK.

This should display your number column without the commas while retaining the benefits of using a number field (field validation & sorting):

*If you save the number as in the Text format type, sorting will not work correctly.

Comment: This should be a workable workaround, but it will be ugly for my case to add in another field, because I already have 120+ fields. BTW, any idea what is the root cause? Did it happen to all SharePoint user?

Comment: This is OOB behaviour in SharePoint. You can convert number field to text field and add column validation to accept numbers only